# Ресурсы из assets появляются с задержкой

Tags: android

Использовал раньше CustomView с TextPaint для выравнивание текста по ширине. Отлично работал на андроид 7. Но был краш на 4.1 ссылается на конструктор CustomView. Удалил Custom View перешёл на Markdown + CSS. Все отлично. Но при запуске программы сперва отображаются основные элементы макета TextView, картинки а только потом MarkdownView и ресурсы из assets. То есть с задержкой где то 5 секунд и это заметно. Можно как-то исправить? Что посоветуете?

Comment: Вернуться на CustomView и пофиксить баги.

Comment: Не думаю, что от этого что-то зависит сейчас. От CustomView ничего не осталось. Переписал код но задержка все же есть. Попробовал через WebView загрузить html та же проблема. Основные элементы загружаются без задержки а Markdown и WebView с задержкой после загрузки TextView и ImageView. Когда был CustomView не была такая ситуация.